# How to limited the countries list in npm react-phone-number-input package

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when react-phone-number-input use this npm package i want to allow limited countries show in dropdown if user enter other country which is not in list it display error not allow this country there is no prop where i limit the countries

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the docs [here](http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/docs/styleguide/index.html#phoneinput) you'll see you can add a `countries` prop to the component, and provide it with an array of strings. Their example shows this array:

```
["RU", "UA", "KZ"]
```

This would limit the list of countries to just those 3.

Comment: yes  i already try this i want to restrict it only accept these if it is not in dropdown it will display an error of invalid phone number

Answer (score 0):

Build a custom array of countries and then use the parseNumber function from libphonenumber-js library and get the country code from the user input number and compare it of your country list

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this first create list of countries that you want to show in dropdown. Then on Blur run the validation if you want.

```
const whitelisted_conutries = ['WS',  'SB',  'TK',  'TO',  'TV',  'VU',  'WF',  'HK']:
```

then pass this to countries prop of PhoneInput like so,

```
import { isValidPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input';

      <PhoneInput
       defaultCountry="GB"
       flagUrl={'https://flag.pk/flags/4x3/{xx}.svg'}
       countries={whitelist}
       value={phone}
       onChange={(phone) => setState({ phone })}
       onBlur={() =>
       setState({
              hasEnterPhone: true,
              error: {
                ...error,
                phone: !phone
                  ? ''
                  : !isValidPhoneNo(phone) &&
                    'Please enter a valid mobile phone number.',
              },
            })
          }
        />
```

For more info on supported props refer developers docs tagged by [@jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2033050/jamie-fenrir-digital-ltd) in thread: [Docs](http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/docs/styleguide/index.html#phoneinput)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the prop `countryPickerProps`

```
<PhoneInput
  countryPickerProps={{
    countryCodes: ['IN', 'GB', 'US'],
  }}
/>
```